# Cross-module reference resolution error - verilog checks for undefined cross-module reference

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I am working on an environment which has different compilation primitives as like

1. `COMP_ALL_MODULES` - for compiling all modules
2. `COMP_SELECT_MODULES` - for compiling a selected set of modules

As such I am facing below error for COMP_SELECT_MODULES and not in COMP_ALL_MODULES

> Error found while trying to resolve the cross-module reference. token
>   'BLK_B'

for below source code

```
assign clock = top.dut.BLK_B.clk;
```

It so happens that COMP_SELECT_MODULES does not compile BLK_B thus causing the error.

As in C programming, I tried 'ifdef checks as shown below. But that compiled out the clock assignment even for COMP_ALL_MODULES.

```
`ifdef top.dut.BLK_B
assign clock = top.dut.BLK_B.clk;
`else
assign clock = 1'b0;
`endif
```

Can you all please suggest about how to have a check for undefined Cross-module references as shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely you want

```
`ifndef COMP_SELECT_MODULES 
  assign clock = top.dut.BLK_B.clk;
`else
  assign clock = 1'b0;
`endif
```

The `ifdef statement tests whether a particular symbol has been defined (eg `COMP_ALL_MODULES  or `COMP_SELECT_MODULES) NOT whether a particular place in the hierarchy exists or not.

Comment: I was thinking more of a way to check if given Cross-module reference exists and then assign the same to clock.
Any suggestions?

Comment: @Chandrabhanu I don't think you can do that without doing something fancy using the PLI.

Comment: Well the error is

    `Error found while trying to resolve the cross-module reference. token 'BLK_B'`

Can we not have a check if BLK_B itself is defined or not?

Comment: @Chandrabhanu I don't think you can in SystemVerilog. You might be able to use the PLI.

Comment: can you help elaborate how verilog PLI can be used to achieve above?

Comment: @Chandrabhanu I can't, I'm afraid. I don't know much about the PLI.(But I do know what it's for, which is why I suggested it. But frankly, I'd say using the PLI was overkill and doing something like I've suggested is the way to go.)